# Access Values from Cloud foundry Vcap Services for values not in JSON

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

How to access VCAP values for this JSON setup in VCAP.

```
System-Provided:
{
 "VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "user-provided": [
   {
    "binding_name": null,
    "credentials": {
     "uri": "ABCD"
    },
    "instance_name": "sample",
    "label": "user-provided",
    "name": "sample",
    "syslog_drain_url": "",
    "tags": [],
    "volume_mounts": []
   },
   {
    "binding_name": null,
    "credentials": {},
    "instance_name": "sample-instance",
    "label": "user-provided",
    "name": "sample",
    "syslog_drain_url": "sample",
    "tags": [],
    "volume_mounts": []
   }
  ]
 }
}

{
 "VCAP_APPLICATION": {
  "application_id": "test-app",
  "application_name": "test-app",
  "application_uris": [
   "abcd.com",
   "abcd.internal"
  ],
  "application_version": "sample",
  "cf_api": "https://sample.com",
  "limits": {
   "disk": 1024,
   "fds": 16384,
   "mem": 1024
  },
  "name": "sample",
  "organization_id": "sample-org",
  "organization_name": "sample",
  "process_id": "sample",
  "process_type": "web",
  "space_id": "sample",
  "space_name": "Validation",
  "uris": [
   "sample.com",
   "sample.internal"
  ],
  "users": null,
  "version": "sample"
 }
}

User-Provided:
ACCESS_KEY_ID: sample
APP_NAME: sample
APP_STAGE: sample
CDL_BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY_ID: sample
CDL_BUCKET_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: sample
CDL_FOLDER_BUCKET: sample
DB_SERVICE_NAME: sample
```

How do i access the below values in spring boot application.

CDL_BUCKET_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
CDL_BUCKET_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

I used this in my application properties file , but its not working-

s3-access-key: ${vcap.services.myservice.CDL_BUCKET_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}

"myservice" being the ServiceName and the key that i want to access.

I could not find anything online to access these kind of values.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i access the below values in spring boot application.
>
> CDL_BUCKET_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, CDL_BUCKET_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

Those are separate environment variables. They are not part of `VCAP_SERVICES`, which is why they are listed in the `User Provided` section of the output of `cf env`.

At the lowest level, you can use [`System.getEnv(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String)) to fetch them.

That said, Spring Boot has support for [external configuration](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-properties-env-variables#use-environment-variables-in-the-applicationproperties-file) and a [relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.2/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding) of external configuration to properties in the application. You could take advantage of this to [map these environment variables to properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.0.2/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables).

For example, `CDL_BUCKET_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` would be available as a property `cdl.bucket.secret.access.key`. You could reference `@Value("${cdl.bucket.secret.access.key"}")` in your app and it should get that value.

You can also just access an [environment variable](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-properties-env-variables#use-environment-variables-in-the-applicationproperties-file) directly but it is more flexible if you access it in the property format because you can then configure that through all of the ways supported by Spring Boot External Configuration not just env variables.